# How can I add an anticipation horizon to my OLS regression?

Tags: r, least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, lm

I am currently writing my thesis and have to submit in 1 week, but am struggling to solve this issue on my own. I would therefore genuinely appreciate your input!

The research question I'm trying to tackle within my thesis is:

Does competition between development assistance donor countries affect democratization in African recipient countries?

I use panel data for 49 African countries from 2000-2013 and employ time- and unit-fixed effects, which leads me to the following equation:

`Polity_it = α_t+ α_i+ β*Treatment_it + x + e_it`

where Polity_it is the level of democracy outcome for unit  at a time , respectively, α_t stands for the time fixed effect, α_i is a unit fixed effect and Treatment_it is the treatment dummy variable indicating whether the unit  has participated in the treatment at time . β is the parameter of interest, hence, the average effect of participating in the treatment. x is a placeholder for covariates and e_it is the standard error.

I have two questions:

1. I assume, that by adding unit and time fixed effects, the interaction term between the treatment and the time variable is being subsumed and the binary Treatment_it dummy can therefore be used to capture the effect of treatment directly. Is that correct or do I still have to include an interaction term in the equation?
2. I use R for my statistical analysis. For the OLS regression, I use the 'lm' command. Since treatment anticipation is likely in the case of my research, the NEPT assumption may be violated (no treatment effect on the outcome in pre-treatment period). To test for this statistically, I want to run two additional analyses with the same equation, however, with anticipation horizon included (one year and two years, respectively). How can I correctly incorporate anticipation in the equation shown above on the one side, and in R on the other side? (the current R codeline is:

`lm(Polity_V2 ~ Treatment + Polity_1999 + ODA2 + Oil + loggdp + logpop + pubcorr + conflict + factor(Year) + factor(ID), data = Paneldatenstruktur_aktuell)`

If the "original" analysis reveals a significantly positive effect and the analysis including anticipation an even stronger positive effect, how should that be interpreted? Does that support the robustness of my findings because it reveals the same trends, or not, because the effect strength increases (yet, in the same direction).

Thank you all in advance!! Your help is much appreciated!